# Authentication with AD Xamarin.Forms

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms

I'm following this [tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin.forms/) to create a login using the Active Directory of Azure Account. When I've logged in, the program crashes instead showing a display with my user name. I've followed almost every step in the exercise.

```
private async void Button_OnClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var auth = DependencyService.Get<IAuthenticator>();
    var data = await auth.Authenticate(authority, graphResourceUri, clientId, returnUri);
    var userName = data.UserInfo.GivenName + " " + data.UserInfo.FamilyName;
    await DisplayAlert("Token", userName, "Ok", "Cancel");
}
```

When I'm debugging the program, it will not enter the line with var userName.
My loginsystem works, because I've connect with the windows login and it takes my e-mailaddress.

Can someone find a mistake in the [tutorial](https://blog.xamarin.com/put-adal-xamarin.forms/) that breaks my program?

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing?

Comment: Can you also show us the implementation of the Authenticate method in the IAuthenticator interface

Comment: I've found the solution. I've created an account in my AD instead of using my MS account.